# Simplest way to get ADO.NET connection string for mdb database

Tags: database, ado.net, odbc, connection-string

I'm learning ADO.NET and have been stuck for DAYS trying to get a connection string for a plain, vanilla .mdb database. I've been trying potential connection strings and permutations but NOTHING works; the database connection is never opened.

The ODBC Data Source Administrator lists the driver as: "Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)". Another application can successfully open this database, so I know my system is capable of it.

Can anyone suggest a SIMPLE connection string that will work?

Answer (score 1):

**The solution:**

**Connection String:**
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=path to database.mdb;
or
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=path to database.mdb;

**Example:**
    string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data             Source=C:\ps\Data\Database File\xtreme.mdb;";
    OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    myConn.Open();

(Sorry about the code formatting; the "Code" formatting item doesn't appear to work.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this one.
Create a module and name it as mdlConnection.
Insert this code below. And dont forget to  Import this reference (ADODB).

```
Imports ADODB
        Public Sub openSys()
            On Error GoTo nopath
            con1 = New ADODB.Connection
            con1.CursorLocation = CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
            con1.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " & DBPathS & " ; Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & DBpass)
            xPathU = True
            Exit Sub

    nopath:
            xPathU = False
            MsgBox("Uknown Server Path", vbExclamation)
            con1 = Nothing

        End Sub
```

In your Form Load in any Forms of your Application.

```
 DBPathS = Application.StartupPath & "\Database\MainData.mdb" 'Path of Database
```

Declare a `DBPathS` as String and `con1` as ADODB.Connection and make it Public.

After you done this. Again in your Form_Load in any Form, call the OpenSys like this

`Call OpenSys`

Dont Forget to Import the said Reference above.